# FORMIO questions total newbie

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, formio

I'm tryin to learn FORM.IO, I'm a total newbie and have little knowledge with Javascript or client server or cloud.
I have some questions, really sorry if they sound stupid.

Is there a difference between resource and form in FORM.IO?
I'm thinking they are the same except that the resource are to be used in forms for drop down or choices? like querying from a table?
I'm trying to use FORM.IO to create an application form where the user client will enter information like their name, address , birthday, complaint and other information .  for this application, am i correct that we only need to use form ? and  FORMIO will also be able to save all the information entered? and resource is just for choices or reference?

Also when planning to embed using the online FORMIO form, how do you connect to MONGODB?
is it possible? or does FORMIO have to be deployed somewhere before you can connect it to MONGODB on Amazon EC2?

Sorry, not sure if my questions make sense or not.
attached is the screenshot of the sample application form i'm trying to create using formio.

thanks.

[Sample application form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtuzZ.png)
[Sample form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nl48.png)

Answer (score 0):

Technically resources and forms are the same thing except for one thing: resources can be embedded in other resources and forms while forms cannot be.

Conceptually, though, they are different. Resources represent entities of your domain. On the other hand, forms represent data that cannot exist on their own; data that depend on entities. Therefore, forms cannot exist on their own, they depend on resources (again, **conceptually**, speaking).

Funny, your sample is about patients, physicians and hospitals. This is almost the same with the sample provided by form.io to explain the difference between resources and forms: https://help.form.io/intro/overview#forms-and-resources

So, no, you do not only need forms for your application.

As for the mongodb question, no, you do not access the data store directly. Instead, you make use of the form.io api that has to be deployed somewhere.